# Pageflex Storefront crashes when making virtual directory (IIS newb)

Tags: iis, deployment, wizard, storefront

I am trying to install the sample deployment from pageflex storefront using the deployment wizard. Everything works until I click finish. When it gets to creating the virtual directory, the program stops responding.

Another related issue may be that I get the message "cannot enumerate available websites" when starting the deployment wizard. I am pretty new to this whole IIS thing so I have probably messed up somewhere in that.

I wish I could be more specific, but no one else seems to have this problem, and none of the documentation files from pageflex even entertain the idea that the deployment wizard would ever crash.

Any help?

EDIT: This turned out to be a database access issue. Make sure you have the right privileges as stated in the documentation.

Comment: I doubt most folk know what pageflex is. Luckily I've installed many sites, do you have any more information? Screen shots? The cannot enumerate available websites should have a follow up piece of information such as - "The system cannot find the path specified" perphaps.  Check the "Home Directory" for the site (under the home directory tab in the sites properties) to make sure that it is pointing to a valid location. Also ensure the user accounts have permission to where the deployment will live.

Comment: The entire error is "Cannot enumerate available websites. Only the default web site will be made available." This is an image of it: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/696/deploymenterror.png/ it happens after I click the next button. In the meantime I'll check on the permissions because that could be the problem. EDIT: Weird, whenever I uncheck "read only" on the default web site, it re-checks itself.

Comment: EDIT 2: Here's an image of it crashing http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/40/deploymentcrash.png/ Also I notice the new directories are being created successfully by the deployment wizard after fixing the physical path, so I guess I am making progress.

Comment: Is there anything on the default website? Does it currently display anything?

Comment: No there is nothing on it (except the directories the wizard creates). In IIS it looks like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/341/defaultwebsite.png/

Comment: After enabling directory browsing I can browse the installed deployment files on the default website. That all seems in order, so I wonder what the crashing is about then.

Comment: So perhaps it was working despite crashing? You can see the login screen etc now?

Comment: No, I cannot see that screen. I think it's actually the database - nothing is being written to it. Sorry if I was leading you down the wrong path, but thanks for helping me narrow the problem.

Comment: np, Good luck. If possible come back and add the answer if you find it to help others in the future.